# How do I configure IntelliJ 11.0 so that Git commits will not replace the entire file contents?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 11.0 and I'm having a problem with my Git commits. I'm pushing my commits to Github, but when I check Github's commit logs, it shows that I'm removing **everything** from a file, and then re-adding every single line. Naturally, this makes it very hard to look at the diffs. Is there a way for me to configure IntelliJ or Git so that it doesn't do this, and shows me the proper diffs?

Comment: In what operating system are you working?

Comment: This would be Windows. You probably already know at this point, but the problem is with those gosh-darned line endings.

Comment: yeah that's what I was thinking, but since you're on Windows, I don't have a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual recommendation is to set core.autocrlf to true in your global .gitconfig on Windows. This will give you CRLF line endings in your working directory and LF line endings in the repository. The conversion happens when files are checkout out into the working directory and when they are committed back into the repository.

The one thing I do not know is whether IntelliJ actually honors that setting, but I'd be very, very surprised if it did not. (Of course, as I understand it, Eclipse has some trouble with it, so maybe I shouldn't be surprised...)

Comment: I ended up doing this. IntelliJ will use CRLF, but Git will convert it to LF on commit.

Answer (score 4):

If it's really the problem with line endings - you can change IntelliJ behavior in `Settings -> Version Control -> Git`. If you set the setting on `Do not convert` IntelliJ doesn't mess with it.

Comment: I dont see this setting in 2019.2 version, I do see a checkbox to warn on clrf changes